# Keep item value using onBindViewHolder in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I am working in `RecyclerView` where I am getting a list of Strings. I want to keep the value of particular `textView` if I am clicking on it, problem is that when I am scrolling down and coming Up again, it is not showing me that clicked value on that `TextView`. I am displaying "Selected", but when I am scrolling and coming again it is showing me default value from that Strings list.

I am putting my code and my screenshot below.

My `onBindViewHolder` code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder  holder,final int position) {

    final String parseObject = arrayList.get(position);

    if (holder instanceof MemberViewHolder) {

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {

            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText(parseObject);
            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setTextColor(R.color.red_theme);
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText("Selected");
                }
            });

        }
}
}
```

These Values I am selecting:

[image: image 1]

These random selected values are showing which I am getting on scrolling, but I didn't clicked them.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: You need to save the state on click into your dataset .And Set it in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: As your arrayList is like (List<String>). As suggested by ADM you need to make custom object array list to keep flag for each such object and in your onClick you need to make that flag true. Then in your onBindViewHolder you have to check flag and then decide display selected or number.

Comment: @halfer got your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `pojo` class like this

```
public class Test {
    public String value;
    public boolean IsSelected;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return IsSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        IsSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

now Create the `ArrayList` of that pojo class

```
ArrayList<Test>arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
```

now when you get list from server than add data in `arraylist` like this

```
 // add item in list like this when you get list from server
    Test test= new Test();
    test.setValue("value");
    arrayList.add(test);
```

Now pass the `ArrayList` in your adapter class

when you click any item in `viewholder` than just set boolean variable in your list

**Example**

```
((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setTextColor(R.color.red_theme);
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText("Selected");
                    arrayList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                }
            });
```

When you set text inside `Textview` just use this condition

```
if(arrayList.get(position).isSelected()){
    txtTicket.setText("Selected");
 }else {
    txtTicket.setText(arrayList.get(position).getValue());
 }
```

Comment: Rathod thanks for your answer here. I followed your code, but problem is that it is showing me Required: Test but found String   final String parseObject = arrayList.get(position);  arrayList is my list of strings which I am getting from server as well.. I changed the list Name as well, but didn't work

Comment: @UKhan  did u create pojo class and also use like this `String parseObject = arrayList.get(position).getValue();`

Comment: How will I pass my list coming from server to your arrayList? Because I have to pass my items. Above code doesn't have any item from server.

Comment: @UKhan check updated ans i have added code how to add data in arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in `onClick()` of `txtTicket` :

```
arrayList.set(position,"Selected");
```

**Edit** put below code in `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
if (parseObject.equalsIgnoreCase("Selected")) {
            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setTextColor(R.color.red_theme);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. By putting this line, it is keeping my selected Values in TextView. But it is not keeping Color of my textView, like when I am selecting it is making it RED, but when I am scrolling and going back to that item, it is showing BLACK color. I want to keep the color of those selected Items as well.

Comment: Thanks. I am waiting for it, I will let you know after updating it,

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll down and up again your onBindViewHolder method will be executed again. You have to save the selected state. For example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder  holder,final int position) {

    final String parseObject = arrayList.get(position);

    if (holder instanceof MemberViewHolder) {

        if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
            if ((Boolean)((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.getTag())) {
                ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText("Selected");
            } else{
                ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText(parseObject);
            }

            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText(parseObject);
            ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                        
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setTextColor(R.color.red_theme);
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setText("Selected");
                    ((MemberViewHolder) holder).txtTicket.setTag(new Boolean(true));

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one pojo class that has string and boolean value like below code..

```
public class Data {
private String value;
private boolean selectedFlag;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public boolean isSelectedFlag() {
    return selectedFlag;
}

public void setSelectedFlag(boolean selectedFlag) {
    this.selectedFlag = selectedFlag;
}
```

}

and pass this pojo class into adapter in and make interface to handel click event like below code ..

```
  List<Data> mDataList = new ArrayList<>();// hear you can pass any pojo class object.

onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;


public void setOnItemClickListner(RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner {
    void onClick(Data str);//pass your object types.
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Data data = mStringList.get(position); // if you pass object of class then create that class object.
    if (data.isSelectedFlag()) {
        holder.textView.setText("Selected");
    }
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onClick(data);
        }
    });
}
```

In activity after adapter bind into recycler view used below code..

```
        recyclerViewAdpater.setOnItemClickListner(new RecyclerViewAdpater.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(Data str) {
            str.setSelectedFlag(true);
            recyclerViewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one pojo class,

```
public class Pojo{
    String id;
    private boolean isSelected;

  public Pojo(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }


  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
  }

  public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
  }
}
```

Firstly position setTag,

```
holder.txtTicket.setTag(position);


holder.txtTicket.setSelected(arrayList.get(position).isSelectedFlag());
    final int pos = position;
    holder.txtTicket.setTag(arrayList.get(position));
```

then in onClick event put this,

```
Pojo pojo = (Pojo) txtTicket.getTag();
pojo.setSelected(txtTicket.isSelected());
```